# How to separate project containers in different VPS?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vps

I'm currently learning how to build projects infrastructures.

Let's suppose that I want to build a project with React, Golang and Postgres using Docker and Docker Compose.

Is there a possible way (or an easy one) to build these 3 containers and deploy it in 3 different VPS?

Containers:

- React = Frontend
- Golang = Backend
- Postgres = Main database

For example:

Dev environment folder structure should be something like:

```
/Project
  /frontend
  /backend
  /database
  docker-compose.yml
  .gitignore
  ...
```

and then, these containers have their own VPS separately.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Hey yeah it is possible if you configure docker in [swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) mode or if you use a container orchestrator like [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io).